# How to make sure that the line down is run after the function above is executed completely in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-development-server

I am writing a function and I want that code on the last 2 lines should be run after the code above it in the function setitems() is  processed completely

```
function addItems(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    setitems(function(previousValue){
        var newArray = [...previousValue, data];
        console.log("new array "+newArray);
        setdata("")
        return newArray;
    })
    console.log("all item "+allitems);
    props.callBackFunction(allitems);
}
```

currently, the thing is that first the last 2 lines are being processed and then after that setitems() function is being processed? please help me out that what can I do in this scenario

Comment: You can take a look at the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I am new to react and this is my first project can you please elaborate that how to implement it, your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: The current answers focus on the ReactJS solution. If you want a non-react answer, you would want to use a `Promise` for the `setItems` function and wait for that to respond before executing the last 2 lines. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` is a react hook which is capable of running function after a defined effect or at any effect. You can use this hook to run that two line when `all items` changed.

```
// usEffect hook
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("all item "+allitems);
    props.callBackFunction(allitems);
}, [allitems]);


// Your function
function addItems(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    setitems(function(previousValue){
        var newArray = [...previousValue, data];
        console.log("new array "+newArray);
        setdata("")
        return newArray;
    })
}
```

This last array at `useEffect` is called as dependency array and whenever any variable values changed which included in that array, the function defined inside will act immediately.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use the [Effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

Take a look at the following sample code, here `useEffect` will run when the component mounts and also when `num` changes

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function App() {
  const [nums, setNums] = useState([]);
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setNums([...nums, Math.random()])
    
    console.log("Inside Click Handler", nums); 
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Inside useEffect hook", nums);
  }, [nums])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
      {nums.map((n, i) => (<li key={i}>{n}</li>))}
      </ul>
      <button id="contact" onClick={handleClick}>Add Random Num</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```